# How do I build a Cassandra image with setup configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra

I am trying to solve a problem that setting cassandra database takes a long time, as it takes about 2.5 minutes to initialize the DB with seed data. I am thinking about a solution that also captures the seed data in a custom docker image with the following steps:

1. Pull the official cassandra image
2. Run my seed.cql file
3. Build a custom image that has the seed.cql data in it
4. Host the custom image on AWS ECR

But I figure out there is no way to actually do step 3 since the docker image does not persist the data storage as I expect.

Any suggestions to reduce the cassandra setup time, or workarounds of step 3?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the image, you need to expose properties in `cassandra.yaml` as environment variables so you can override them in your Docker compose file.

For example:

```
services:
  cassandra:
    image: ...
    ...
    environment:
      - SEEDS=...
  ...
```

Alternatively, it will allow you to specify the seeds via CLI with the `-e` flag:

```
$ docker run ... -e SEEDS=$_seeds_list ...
```